# Where would you place scroll indicator buttons? Left or right of content?

Tags: website-design, navigation, buttons, touch-screen, scrolling

I was wondering if there were any A/B tests carried out for where scroll indicator buttons should be placed. See for example [Acquia.com](http://www.acquia.com/), they have up and down scroll buttons placed, which is good for touch based interfaces. However, these can be placed left or right, I was wondering if there are arguments for either side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporting the case for placing it on the right:

- Normally a user would read, or at least scan, the content before thinking about scrolling. In that scenario it would make more sense to have the scroll buttons on the right side (assuming of course that the content is being read left to right).
- The scroll bar position for vertical scrolling is on the right hand side of the content being scrolled in every OS I can think of.

Comment: But you don't want to clutter the screen if there is already a scroll bar on the right. So the implementation on [Acquia.com](http://www.acquia.com) is not the best?

Comment: I didn't see this anywhere else, so was just wondering what are the benefits, and if there is research that at least explored that possibility. No mentioning of left scroll elements on Nielsen either: [nngroup.com](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-attention/)

Comment: @sPLUS Even in a web browser, the developer can control if the scroll bar is displayed. If it looks cluttered with the scroll bar and the buttons, then I would hide the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

To the right. Nearly all users have an existing mental model of where things "should" be. I wouldn't break the scroll-control-on-the-right convention unless a very specific product or user goal demanded it. If that goal is too confuse and then annoy, go for it.